# excel vba change txt file name (remove time)

Tags: excel, text-files, filenames, vba

How do I programmatically change the file name of a .txt using excel vba, I need a script where it will go through a folder which consists of txt files and remove time from its filename.

Original Filename: ABC_ABCDE_ABCD_YYYYMMDDTTTTTT.txt
New Filename: ABC_ABCDE_ABCD_YYYYMMDD.txt

Thank you in advance

Mike

Comment: What did you try so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: @Storax - I have a macro that opens the txt files but have to rename it manually, I need a macro that will change the filename without opening the txt files (if possible)

Comment: @MichaelMC is your original file format is always like this "ABC_ABCDE_ABCD_YYYYMMDDTTTTTT.txt" ?

Comment: You need the NAME x AS y command rather than opening the file

Comment: @DineshPawar - yes, format is always like that, i just need to remove the T(s). A macro that will run through each txt files (about 50+files)

Comment: @HarassedDad - sorry man, not familiar with "NAME x AS y"

Comment: Show us the code (in your question) that loops through all the files and we can then advise what you'll need.

Comment: @CLR - the macro just imports the text files in excel and a sheet are created per txt file, i'm looking for a macro where "if possible" that it will remove the T(s) from the txt filename in a selected folder.

Comment: I understood that Michael, I was just hoping to modify your existing code (as you're more likely to understand and learn from that, than someone just writing a whole new Sub for you). Looks like it's all sorted anyway now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per My understanding of your question, I write a code which asks a user to select the folder and rename ".txt" file as per requirements, you may be add an additional code of line for perfect work

```
'call sub LoopThroughFiles   
'this sub is loop every file and rename it
Sub LoopThroughFiles()

    Dim txtfile As String, folderPath As String
    Dim newName As String

    folderPath = GetFolder()
    txtfile = Dir(folderPath & "\" & "*.txt")

    While txtfile <> ""

          If checkFormat(txtfile) = True Then
             newName = Left(txtfile, 23) & ".txt"
           On Error Resume Next
           'rename file is done here
    If Not txtfile = "" Then Name (folderPath + "\" + txtfile) As (folderPath + "\" + newName)
            On Error GoTo 0

         End If
        txtfile = Dir

    Wend
End Sub

'this function is for check format of file
'you may edit it as per your requirment
Function checkFormat(str As String) As Boolean
checkFormat = False
If Len(str) = 33 And Mid(str, 4, 1) = "_" Then
    checkFormat = True
End If

End Function

'this function for select folder path
Function GetFolder() As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

Before use this code please make an additional copy of your file in case some error you have a backup... 
Hope This help

Comment: @MichaelMC I am glad to know that your problem gets solved, further, you can modify checkformat and newName variable as per your need, also you can pass the direct folder path to LoopThroughFiles() by adding few lines of code .